# Proportionally scale down an array - java

Tags: java

In java, does anyone know how to scale down all array values proportionally if a value reaches MAX_VALUE to ensure all values are below MAX_VALUE?

For example:

```
MAX_VALUE = 11

originalArray has values:
 [0] = 6
 [1] = 20
 [2] = 4
```

Because [1] is 2 times as large as MAX_VALUE-1, we must proportionally divide all array values by 2. So,

```
newArray has values:
[0] = 3
[1] = 10
[2] = 2
```

Thank you!

Comment: So, the way stackoverflow works is you post code that's not working, along with details of what's not working and how you expect it to work, and you don't know why.  This is not a "can someone code this for me" site, especially for stuff which is so obviously homework.  Cheers!

Comment: Also, 6-2=4 not 3... At least it was last time i looked :)

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

1) Iterate over the array and find the maximum value
2) divide the maximum value by MAX_VALUE (You might want to pay attention on what datatype to use to catch/store this value) . Take [ceiling value](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/number_ceil.htm) of this. **
3) Subtract each element in array with the value obtained in step 2

** if you dont want to or can not use the Math library, then you very easily define your own ceiling function.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! I was using values[i] to store the new value of the array instead of this.values[i].

I changed:

```
this.values [0] = (int) (values [0] /  newValue);
this.values [1] = (int) (values [1] /  newValue);
this.values [2] = (int) (values [2] /  newValue);
this.values [3] = (int) (values [3] /  newValue);
this.values [4] = (int) (values [4] /  newValue);
```

Thank you all!